Exception trying to run Bagetter 1.2 Sample Web App on await app.RunMigrationsAsync()
I'm trying to run my own web app using Bagetter v1.2. There is a sample web app in the source code that won't compile, so instead I created my own and pulled in the following NuGet Packages:

Bagetter.Core
Bagetter.Web
Bagetter.SqlLite
Bagetter.SqlServer

I tried first with SQL Server but get an exception in Program.cs on app.RunMigrationsAsync(). I switched back to using SqlLite (including changing the appsettings.json database connection string) but still get an exception on that line.
Dumping the stack trace and exception here :
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'


        StackTrace  "   at BaGetter.Database.Sqlite.SqliteContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)\r\n   at
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()\r\n   at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()\r\n   at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService(IInfrastructure`1 accessor, Type serviceType)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)\r\n   at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_Dependencies()\r\n   at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IDatabaseFacadeDependenciesAccessor.get_Dependencies()\r\n   at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetFacadeDependencies(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)\r\n   at
 crosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetDbConnection(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)\r\n   at
 BaGetter.Database.Sqlite.SqliteContext.<RunMigrationsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n   at 
BaGetter.Web.IHostExtensions.<RunMigrationsAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n   at Program.<<Main>$>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\\code\\OSU.HR\\OSU.HR.NugetServer\\Program.cs:line 27" string

Uh, I tried running the application but am getting an exception
